How to find each of the following coordinate representations?

I understand the basic concept of coordinate representations. I don't understand how to change the basis of a matrix, so explaining why we are doing what we are doing would be most helpful. Thank you.

There have been many many many questions on this website already about change-of-basis matrices. Have a look at the questions listed under Related to see whether your question is a duplicate of one posted previously.

In saying that $S$ is given with respect to the standard bases by
$[S]_{\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{E}} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 3 & -3 \\ 4 & -8 \end{bmatrix}$
we mean that if we have a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ which can be written with respect to $\mathcal{E}$ as $[v]_\mathcal{E} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2\end{bmatrix}$ (or in other words $v = v_1 \mathbf{i} + v_2 \mathbf{j}$), then if we write $Sv$ in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can get its coefficients through matrix multiplication. In particular, we'll have
$[Sv]_\mathcal{E} = \begin{bmatrix} v_2 \\ 3v_1 - 3v_2 \\ 4v_1 - 8v_2 \end{bmatrix} \implies Sv = v_2 \mathbf{i} + (3 v_1 - 3 v_2) \mathbf{j} + (4 v_1 - 8 v_2) \mathbf{k}$
Then changing the basis of the matrix to, for example, $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{E}$ is saying "What matrix represents the transformation $S$ when the input is written as $v = v_{b1} \mathbf{b}_1 + v_{b2} \mathbf{b}_2$ and the output is still in the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$?" You could do this by noting that $v_{b1} \mathbf{b}_1 + v_{b2} \mathbf{b}_2 = (2 v_1 + v_2) \mathbf{i} + (v_1 + v_2) \mathbf{j}$, so $Sv = (v_1 + v_2) \mathbf{i} + (-3 v_1) \mathbf{j} + (-4 v_2) \mathbf{k}$ using the formula we already found, and so
$[S]_{\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{E}} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -3 & 0 \\ 0 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$
Doing that for all of the questions will get tedious, though. A much more efficient way is to note that a change of basis is also a linear transformation which can thus be represented by a matrix, and applying successive linear transformations then turns into matrix multiplication. So if you can find the change of basis matrices for converting between $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and between $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then you can use those to answer everything.
